# Untrackable object attribute

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I am trying to adapt this code here: https://github.com/nachonavarro/gabes/blob/master/gabes/circuit.py (line 136)
but am coming across an issue because several times the attribute `.chosen_label` is used but I can find no mention of it anywhere in the code. The objects `left_gate`, `right_gate` and `gate` are Gate objects (https://github.com/nachonavarro/gabes/blob/master/gabes/gate.py)

```
def reconstruct(self, labels):
    levels = [[node for node in children]
              for children in anytree.LevelOrderGroupIter(self.tree)][::-1]
    for level in levels:
        for node in level:
            gate = node.name
            if node.is_leaf:
                garblers_label = labels.pop(0)
                evaluators_label = labels.pop(0)
            else:
                left_gate = node.children[0].name
                right_gate = node.children[1].name
                garblers_label = left_gate.chosen_label
                evaluators_label = right_gate.chosen_label
            output_label = gate.ungarble(garblers_label, evaluators_label)
            gate.chosen_label = output_label
    return self.tree.name.chosen_label
```

The code runs without error and the `.chosen_label` is a Label object (https://github.com/nachonavarro/gabes/blob/master/gabes/label.py)

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute is set *in the same method*:

```py
for level in levels:
    for node in level:
        gate = node.name
        if node.is_leaf:
            # set `garblers_label` and `evaluators_label` from 
            # the next two elements of the `labels` argument 
        else:
            # use the child nodes of this node to use their gates, and
            # set `garblers_label` and `evaluators_label` to the  left and
            # right `chosen_label` values, respectively.
        # generate the `Label()` instance based on `garblers_label` and `evaluators_label`
        output_label = gate.ungarble(garblers_label, evaluators_label)
        gate.chosen_label = output_label
```

I'm not familiar with the `anytree` library, so I had to look up the documentation: the [`anytree.LevelOrderGroupIter(...)` function](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/anytree.iterators.html#anytree.iterators.levelordergroupiter.LevelOrderGroupIter) orders the nodes in a tree from root to leaves, grouped by level. The tree here appears to be a balanced binary tree (each node has either 0 or 2 child nodes), so you get a list with `[(rootnode,), (level1_left, level1_right), (level2_left_left, level2_left_right, level2_right_left, level2_right_right), ...]`. The function loops over these levels in reverse order. This means that *leaves are processed **first***.

Once all `node.is_leaf` nodes have their `chosen_label` set, the other non-leaf nodes can reference the `chosen_label` value on the leaf nodes on the level already processed before them.

So, assuming that `labels` is a list with at least twice the number of leaf nodes in the tree, you end up with those label values aggregated at every level via the `gate.ungarble()` function, and the final value is found at the root node via `self.tree.name.chosen_label`.

Comment: Thanks, I think my confusion stems from not realising new attributes can be created 'outside' of the class

Comment: Also can I check you meant the first two elements not the last two in the if block @martijnpieters

Comment: @HenryGarrett: ah, yes, the first two, I missed the `0` argument there.